# How to find checkbox value when using Appium C# driver?

Tags: c#, appium

I am using C# Appium driver AppiumDriver

Need to get checkbox value for ShowInMarkbookLocator on iOS device

First I tried with

```
   _driver.FindElement(ShowInMarkbookLocator).GetAttribute("checked")
```

It returns empty string.

then tried with..

```
   _driver.FindElement(ShowInMarkbookLocator).Selected
```

It gives an error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error (An unknown
>   server-side error occurred. status='false'. Failed to complete
>   internal method: 'elementGetProperty args: [NATIVE,
>   xpath=(//[@text='Markbook'])[1], 0, selected]', details: Failed to get
>   property from 'xpath=(//[@text='Markbook'])[1]'. Could not connect to
>   an application on the device)

checkbox locator ShowInMarkbookLocator is correct, I am able to check enabled value for it

Is there another way to get checkbox value?

Comment: If "checked" is a valid attribute, it might be that the attribute only exists if it is checked and does not exist if it is not checked, so you might interpret an empty string return as unchecked.  Obviously you'd need to confirm this by viewing the DOM in both states.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the state of `CheckBox.IsChecked` like this:

```
string state = myAppiumWebElement.GetAttribute("Toggle.ToggleState");
```

### Possible results

"0" is unchecked

"1" is checked

"2" is undefined (e.g. for elements
without toggle state)